# CSS3 Transform FireFox/chrome vs ie 11

Tags: html, css

I have a little problem with a css layout

So I want to align some divs inline and move them like 3 pixels up (to make the look perfect)

It's working fine in IE10/11 but not in FireFox and chrome.

I cannot give you a link, but I can insert some screens

So this is what I want (working on IE10/11)

http://beehiver.jurion.me/ie11.png

And now FireFox :

http://beehiver.jurion.me/firefox.png
Here is my CSS for this part :

```
#buttons {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #526271;
}

    #buttons a {
        color: #526271;
        transition: all 250ms ease-out;
    }


        #buttons a:hover {
            color: #1ab9d6;
        }

    #buttons div {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 100px;
        height: 53px;
        border-left: 1px solid grey;
        vertical-align: top;
        transform: translate(0px,-2px);
        padding-left: 3px;
        text-align: center;
        transition: all 250ms ease-out;
        border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
    }

        #buttons div:hover {
            border-left-color: #1ab9d6;
            border-bottom-color: #1ab9d6;
        }

        #buttons div i {
            font-size: 34px;
            vertical-align: top;
            transform: translate(0px,10px);
            display: block;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
        }
```

I just can not find why it's not working :(

EDIT :

Answer by   J McFee :

inline-block is sensitive to whitespace, i recommend floating your divs.

Works fine ! (generates a little problem which I can resolve, unrelated to the question)

Changes :

```
#buttons div {
    float:left;
```

and

```
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

Comment: inline-block is sensitive to whitespace, i recommend floating your divs

Comment: There is IE11 already o_O. SO is like a newsfeed for me sometimes :-)

Comment: That worked ! Post it as answer to upvote :p

Comment: Out of topic : yes win 8.1 was released today. So ie11 is out ^^ pretty good actually haha :p

Answer (score 0):

assuming "#buttons div" is inside "#buttons" try changing this:

```
#buttons {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #526271;
}
```

to

```
#buttons {
    display: block;
    color: #526271;
    height:53px;
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks you. But the #buttons is part of another div and must be displayed inline. It's a header. I tested your solution, it's not working :(

Comment: well, adding your html code would help a lot, otherwise I just have to imagine what do you want to do

Comment: Yes I know, but it will be a lot of html : like 50 lignes.